# Call custom phtml on success page without override

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In Magento 2 I want to call my custom `phtml` file order success page, but without overriding block. Is there any way to achieve this ?

I don't want to edit Magento `success.phtml` as I am creating module.

Any help will appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use any of Magento's layout file in your module to insert your custom block. In your case you need to use `checkout_onepage_success.xml` layout file in your custom module which will be active when a customer is on order success page. In the layout file you need to specify where you want to add your custom template using `referenceContainer` or `referenceBlock`.

For you I've created a simple module and tested it which works fine.

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Amit_Orderpage',
    __DIR__
);
```

**composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "amit/orderpage-module",
  "description": "Simple Magento 2 module that adds a new template on order success page.",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "~100.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Amit\\Orderpage\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Amit_Orderpage" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**Block/Success.php**

```
<?php
namespace Amit\Orderpage\Block;
class Success  extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getSomething()
    {
        return 'returned something from custom block.';
    }
}
```

**view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
        <block class="Amit\Orderpage\Block\Success"
               name="amit.order.success"
               template="Amit_Orderpage::order/success.phtml"
               after="-">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Specify `before` or `after` tag to specify where you want to add your template before or after `order.success.additional.info` container. Here `after="-"` will add your your template to `order.success.additional.info` container after all other containers present in the same section.

**view/frontend/templates/order/success.phtml**

```
<?php /* @var $block \Amit\Orderpage\Block\Success */?>
<?php echo __('Custom template file content.'); ?>
<?php echo $block->getSomething(); ?>
```

Comment: I don't want to edit magento success.phtml , I want to achieve this by xml or event as I am creating extension.

Comment: @Smith answer updated as per your comment.

Comment: This helped a lot. +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to utilize/access the current $order object in your block/html file, without overriding original order success block/template. Here is the complete solution:

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MageAj_OrderSuccess',
    __DIR__
);
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="MageAj_OrderSuccess" setup_version="2.0.0" />
</config>
```

**app/code/MageAj/OrderSuccess/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="mageaj.success" template="MageAj_OrderSuccess::checkout/onepage/success.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">MageAj\OrderSuccess\ViewModel\Checkout\Onepage\Success</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>        
    </body>    
</page>
```

**app/code/MageAj/OrderSuccess/ViewModel/Checkout/Onepage/Success.php**

```
<?php

namespace MageAj\OrderSuccess\ViewModel\Checkout\Onepage;

class Success implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession        
    ) {        
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;       
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    }
}
```

**app/code/MageAj/OrderSuccess/view/frontend/templates/order/success.phtml**

```
<?php $order = $block->getViewModel()->getOrder(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to create new module, you can do it in your theme as well.
Follow below steps:

1.Create **`checkout_onepage_success.xml`** in your theme. For example:

> app/design/frontend///Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml.

**The content of file is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success"
               name="custom_info.order.success"
               template="Magento_Checkout::order/success/custom_info.phtml"
               after="-">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

2.Then you need to create the template file:

> app/design/frontend///Magento_Checkout/templates/order/success/custom_info.phtml

You can add any content in the template. For example:

```
<?php /* @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success */?>
<?php echo __('Custom template file content.'); ?>
<?php echo $block->getSomething(); ?>
```

Clear the cache and you are done.

Comment: This helped a lot. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

In checkout_onepage_success.xml:-

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"/>
```

Missed my code before , can you check my answer now.

[fschmengler](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/243/fschmengler)

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Can you add a bit more information how to use it? As it stands the answer is not very useful.

Answer (score -1):

you can used referenceContainer or referenceBlock to add your phtml file in order sucess page.

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.success">
      <block class="[Company]\[Vendor]\Block\[Yourblock]" template="Company_Vendor::yourfile.phtml" name="[Yourblock Name]"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more information how to use it? As it stands the answer is not very useful.