# Magento 2:How to change validation message in checkout page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want to just update the text of validation message in checkout page how can I achieve that?

Comment: you can override template default to do this.

Comment: you can use translate csv to achieve that

Comment: Which template i need to override? @MichaelHa

Comment: you can find it in  vendor -> magento -> module_checkout

Comment: In checkout i don't find any form which contain the shipping address form like firstname, last name etc @MichaelHa

Comment: it will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136730/call-custom-phtml-on-success-page-without-override?noredirect=1&lq=1 very simple. don't need override.